# Taking group of MXDs and using a batch command make them all into map packages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, map-package

I work for a company where one of our deliverables is a map package of every map layout we put into a report, so about 20 map packages typically.

While going through a whole list of files yet again and manually sharing each one as a map package I was wondering if there was a way in ArcCatalog or if a tool exists to do this as a batch process?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  [Here is a link to the Package Map tool in ArcToolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/package-map.htm).  The link includes Python code (example 2) for taking all of the MXDs in a directory and converting them to map packages.  You would only need to change the path to the working directory to the location of your MXDs.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that your DataFrames (Maps) are missing required information, in this case the Description.

[image: Data Frame Properties]

So you need to complete this for every DataFrame that is missing this information. Here is a simple python script you run in an IDE that will go through a folder opens up the MXD then goes through all DataFrames and inserts/overwrites a Description. All properties accessible are listed in the help file [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm#P_GUID-48F7EC9F-155E-4816-BA5D-F7A46E9890FC).

```py
import glob
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Folder with MXD's
folder = r"C:\Scratch\UWR"

# Create a list of MXD's to process
lstMXD = glob.glob(folder + r"\*.mxd")
print(lstMXD)

# Main loop
for mxdPath in lstMXD:
    print("Processing: " + mxdPath)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*"):
        df.description = "Some generic text to put in Description"

    # overwrite MXD
    mxd.save()
```